# FreeBSD script to add user

Tags: shell, freebsd

I'm trying to write a script to add user to FreeBSD. The problem of adduser command in FreeBSD is that it gets information from me, step by step. Like, after i run adduser, it asks for username; after i enter username, it asks for full name, and so on. So now my script needs to give the input, step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `useradd` [1]? It works also on FreeBSD using `pw`. And if `pw` is not accessible from the script directly, you can use full path as `/usr/sbin/pw` which should work everywhere

- [1] https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=useradd&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD+5.6&arch=default&format=html
- [2] http://linuxg.net/create-users-on-freebsd-systems-with-useradd/

Comment: but that's not for FreeBSD. in FreeBSD we have adduser, and the one i said above, is the only method i know that works.

Comment: Why do you think that freeBSD doens't have `useradd`? Of course it has such command: 
http://linuxg.net/create-users-on-freebsd-systems-with-useradd/

Comment: Using pw? Yes I've tried that with terminal, but in the script, i get this error: pw:not found

Comment: And do you run your script privileged? Have you tried with full path to `pw`

Comment: it worked with full address. for me it was in /usr/sbin. thanks. :)

Comment: I did; Could you just edit your answer with a little details on full address and pw for others. thanks :)